# Is there anyway to run multiple-procedures back-to-back in PL/SQL so that a table is created and then filled in as structured in my code?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working with Oracle SQL Developer and I am trying get the below code to work and just can't figure it out. I have tried multiple different methods including implementing for loops, execute immediate's, scheduling and recompiling.

```
BEGIN
  ORDER_STATUS_1_DROP_TABLE;    -- If the table exist, drop it
  ORDER_STATUS_2_CREATE_TABLE;  -- Create the table
  GRANT_NEWANALYTICS;           -- Grant users select access
  ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT;        -- Run script to insert data into table
END;
```

What the code is trying to do is this:

Procedure 1: Drop  if exist, otherwise skip. I don't want to see any warning errors stating that no table exist if this procedure is run when there is no table. This procedure by itself does work as intended.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ORDER_STATUS_1_DROP_TABLE IS 
    table_does_not_exist EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(table_does_not_exist, -942);
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE <Table Name>';
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN table_does_not_exist then
    dbms_output.put_line( 'table dose not exist');
  END ORDER_STATUS_1_DROP_TABLE;
```

Procedure 2: Once the table is dropped, this procedure recreates it with the correct . I don't want to see any errors for "this table already exist" and that is why, in part, procedure 1 exists. This by itself works as intended.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ORDER_STATUS_2_CREATE_TABLE IS
    v_sql LONG;
  BEGIN
    v_sql:= 'create table <Table Name>
      (<parameters>)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
  END ORDER_STATUS_2_CREATE_TABLE;
```

Procedure 3: This just gives users select access to the table created in the last procedure. This procedure works as it was intended.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GRANT_NEWANALYTICS IS 
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
      'GRANT SELECT ON <Table Name> TO <UserID>';
  END;
```

Procedure 4: This is a complicated query. It is an insert select all from (table left join to a few other tables based upon fields and conditions, etc). After procedures 1-3 are run, this procedure by itself has not issue running, but by itself.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT IS 

  BEGIN
    DELETE FROM <Table Name>;
    INSERT INTO <Table Name>
    SELECT * FROM(<Multiple Table Joins>);
  END ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT;
```

When I run the procedures like this:

```
  BEGIN
   ORDER_STATUS_1_DROP_TABLE;    -- If the table exist, drop it
   ORDER_STATUS_2_CREATE_TABLE;  -- Create the table
   GRANT_NEWANALYTICS;           -- Grant users select access
   ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT;        -- Run script to insert data into table
  END;
```

I get the following error report:

```
Error report -
ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped stored procedure "<user>.ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT"
ORA-06508: PL/SQL: could not find program unit being called: "<user>.ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT"
ORA-06512: at line 5
04068. 00000 -  "existing state of packages%s%s%s has been discarded"
*Cause:    One of errors 4060 - 4067 when attempt to execute a stored procedure.
*Action:   Try again after proper re-initialization of any application's state.
```

Now, If I run these separately, it works. So if I first run this:

```
 BEGIN
  ORDER_STATUS_1_DROP_TABLE;    -- If the table exist, drop it
  ORDER_STATUS_2_CREATE_TABLE;  -- Create the table
  GRANT_NEWANALYTICS;           -- Grant users select access
END;
<OUTPUT> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

And then this:

```
BEGIN
ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT;        -- Run script to insert data into table
END;
<OUTPUT> <Query runs>
```

I have not issues. I want to run these set of procedures in ones sweep and could use some help on the idea of such. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why drop table?

Comment: It's better use a package with mentioned procedures and dynamic SQL as @Justin Cave suggest

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run all these procedures as a part of a single PL/SQL block then every reference to your table would need to be via dynamic SQL.  So `ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT` would need to use dynamic SQL to build the insert statement(s) to populate the table rather than using simple static SQL.  That's obviously possible but it does increase the complexity of the script.  Potentially substantially.

Having two PL/SQL blocks, which you've demonstrated works, seems much simpler.

Comment: Dropping and recreating tables is basically an anti pattern in  Oracle and is never necessary. It seams you using this as a one time use table (your 3_script) removes all rows before repopulating it. Thus delete and recreate gives no advantage over what truncate in insead 3_script would. That would reduce your entire process to that 1 script. Another option, depending on how data is processed after 3_script may be just create a Global Temporary Table.  Either way ORDER_STATUS_3_SCRIPT is the only script you need.

Comment: Hi Justin. Yeah I get that. There are times where certain source fields are not available from upstream sources and I designed it this way so in the procedure I could comment out any field that isn't available that month. Perhaps I could figure away to say if field isn't available then null. Would have to think about that some. Thanks for the feedback!